# Understanding the computation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(- \pi t^2)\exp(2 \pi i x t/\sqrt{2 \pi}) dt = \exp(-x^2/2)$

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

I've been trying to figure out how the following is true, but I get stuck every time:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{- \pi t^2}e^\dfrac{2 \pi i x t}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} dt = e^{-x^2/2} $$

Comment: You should write what you tried so others can better understand how to help you. Can you write the integrand in the form $e^{- a(t-bx)^2 + c}$, where $a,b,c$ are some constants, ie complete the square? Have you tried that, and are you still stuck after that?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2219266/9464

Comment: Horrible use of `\dfrac` (which I corrected in the title).

Answer (score 0):

You are just stating that the gaussian function is a fixed point of the Fourier transform.
The usual ways for proving it are completing the square and apply a bit of complex analysis (contour integration along a rectangle), or define $f(x)$ as the LHS and check it fulfills a simple differential equation, by differentiation under the integral sign and integration by parts.